# Finding area within set radius using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, shapefile, point, point-in-polygon

I'm new to QGIS and I want to use it to model the land area within a 90km radius of a point.

I have my location and I have 32 shapefiles and I would like to draw a 90km radius around my initial location and determine the area covered by shapefiles within the radius.

Answer (score 1):

To accomplish what you want, Go to Vector > Geoprocessing Tools > Fixed Distance Buffer to create the 90km radius around your initial location.

Next, use Vector > Geoprocessing Tools > Intersection to generate a new layer with the overlap between your buffer and your 32 shapefiles.

Then right click on layer representing the intersection > Attribute Table > Field Calculator. Check create new field, set the output name (e.g., area), and use $area as the expression.

[image]